# Perimeter of triangle $SPR$

Tags: triangles, circles, tangent-line

[image]

I have to calculate perimeter of triangle $SPR$. I know, that length between $A$ and $P$ is $25$. I know that length between $B$ and $P$ is also $25$. Also in $A$ and in $B$ is angle $90$.
Any help?

Comment: The perimeter is 50

Comment: if $PA$ and $PB$ are tangent to the circle then perimeter $\triangle ABC=50$, since $RA=RQ$ and $SQ=SB$

Comment: Draw a line from the center of the circle, say $O$, to $R$, What can you say about $\triangle OAR$ and $\triangle OQR$?

Answer (score 2):

$PR+RS+SP=PR+RQ+QS+SP=PR+RA+BS+SP=AP+BP=25+25=50$